# Using SNMP retrieve IP and MAC addresses of directly connected machines to a SNMP Device

Tags: networking, snmp

How to get connected machine's IP and Mac of SNMP device.

ARP cache is not giving correct details.

Comment: are you trying to get this out of a result of a programming language or from the shell or cmd ?

Answer (score 0):

Example for Linux shell commands (no tag for other languages or Windows at time of writing)

Providing that the machine you want to query does run a SNMP Daemon ( generally snmpd from Net-SNMP under Linux ) and that you know how/are allowed to speak to it ( version 1, 2c or 3 with various community names or usernames/passwords/encoding for v3 ) you may issue the following SNMP requests:

*For the test I started a snmpd on a CentOS 7 virtual machine whose main address was 192.168.174.128.*

*I choose port 1610 over the traditional 161 in order not to sudo or to setcap (snmpd). The snmpd.conf file contents is out of the range of this question.*

This first one for IPs

```
snmptable -v 2c -c private 192.168.174.128:1610 ipAddrTable 

SNMP table: IP-MIB::ipAddrTable

    ipAdEntAddr ipAdEntIfIndex ipAdEntNetMask ipAdEntBcastAddr ipAdEntReasmMaxSize
      127.0.0.1              1      255.0.0.0                0                   ?
  192.168.122.1              3  255.255.255.0                1                   ?
192.168.174.128              2  255.255.255.0                1                   ?
```

The second command (with 3 columns only printed) for MAC

```
snmptable -v 2c -c private 192.168.174.128:1610 ifTable | awk -c '{print $1 "\t" $2 "\t\t" $6}'
SNMP    table:      

ifIndex ifDescr     ifPhysAddress
1       lo          up
2       ens33       0:c:29:53:aa:c6
3       virbr0      52:54:0:e6:6b:2f
4       virbr0-nic      52:54:0:e6:6b:2f
```

When we check under CentOS 7 we get

```
ifconfig
ens33: ...  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.174.128  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.174.255
    inet6 ...
    ether 00:0c:29:53:aa:c6 netmask 255.0.0.0
    ...

lo: ...  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1
    ...

virbr0: ...  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
    ether 52:54:00:e6:6b:2f ...
    ...
```

Bonus shell command:

```
snmptranslate -Oaf IF-MIB::ifTable
.iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2.interfaces.ifTable
```

and

```
snmptranslate -Oaf IP-MIB::ipAddrTable
.iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2.ip.ipAddrTable
```

I do not know why/if there is a single table holding both information.